# Blueimp - fileupload. sube muchas imagenes almacenadas

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, fileupload

Hola comunidad tengo el siguiente problema con `blueimp fileupload`. quiero subir sola una imagen al servidor. Pero cuando selecciono en el **input** de tipo file varias veces y selecciono distintas imágenes recibo todas esas imágenes como si estuviera guardado en dicho **input** el listado de imágenes. En mi **input** borre el atributo `múltiple` y `name="file"` no funciono.

**mi código de jquery es:**

```
$('#photo_news').fileupload({
            url: '/_uploader/gallery/upload',
            type: 'POST',
            multipart: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            autoUpload: false,
            singleFileUploads: true,
            maxNumberOfFiles : 1,
            replaceFileInput: false,
            add: function(e, data){



                $("#form_news").submit(function(e){

                    e.preventDefault();

                    data.formData = $("#form_news").serializeArray();
                    data.submit();


                });

            },
            done: function(e, data) {

                if(data){
                    window.location.reload();
                }

            },

            error: function(e, data){

                console.log(data);

            }

        });
```

Comment: te a pasado seleccionando mas de dos imágenes?

Comment: correcto. si selecciono 2 o mas imagenes se siguen guardando y al enviar al servidor llega todas esas imageness que seleccione

Comment: #file-news supongo es el id del input tuyo , hagamos algo , agrega este código jquery y veamos si te devuelve siempre el ultimo elemento que seleccionaste `$('#upload-input').on('change', function () {var files = $(this).get(0).files; console.log(files[files.length - 1])})`

Comment: #photo_news es mi id "INPUT FILE", lo agrego en add: function(e, data) correcto?

Comment: Agregue afuera y me muestra el file cada ves que seleciono uno.

Comment: dentro no , ponlo fuera lo que te puse es para capturar el cambio del input , para ver si te logro capturar el ultimo ,  con eso podríamos solucionar el problema , ahora te pongo la respuesta con la solución

Comment: genial. lo puse afuera, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a enseñar otra manera de mandar el **input** al servidor , y de esta manera controlaremos que sea el ultimo elemento seleccionado, puedes mantener la propiedad `name="file"` que tenias anteriormente:

```
$('#upload-input').on('change', function () {
       //files tendrá todos los elementos que sean seleccionados, o el único que se seleccione
    var files = $(this).get(0).files;

        var formData = new FormData();
              //si se seleccionaron varios elementos file sera el ultimo que se selecciono
        var file = files[files.length-1];
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);


        $.ajax({
            url: '/_uploader/gallery/upload',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            xhr: function () {
                //este xhr es por si quieres llenar alguna barra de progreso
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100); // esta variable contiene por que % esta la subida
                        if (percentComplete === 100) {
                            // aquí pones que ocurrirá cuando el % sea 100%
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
                return xhr;
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            //aquí declaras lo que ocurrirá cuando se termine de subir el fichero
        });

});
```

> Nota: recuerda que si estas utilizando tu **input** para subir solo imágenes, al **input** puedes incluirle la propiedad **accept** para definir que tipos de imágenes subir, por ejemplo `accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg, image/gif"`
>
> > Ten en cuenta que con lo que te implemente anteriormente en el momento que se realiza la selección , auto-seguido se hace la petición y se envía al servidor , si deseas separarlo , tendrías que poner la función `$.ajax()` en una función aparte , y llamarla cuando desees que se envié.

Answer (score 0):

Probe de otra manera ya que la idea es hacer funcionar con la libreria ya que uso un bundle para symfony y trabajand juntos.

probe de la siguiente manera en este codigo donde solo envia una imagen y no se repite. pero toma la primera imagen y no la ultima.

antes del submit en add. puse al input file disable con fileupload...

```
$('#photo_news').fileupload({
            url: '/_uploader/gallery/upload',
            type: 'POST',
            multipart: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            autoUpload: false,
            singleFileUploads: true,
            replaceFileInput: false,
            maxNumberOfFiles: 1,

            add: function(e, data){

                $("#photo_news").fileupload('disable');

                $("#form_news").submit(function(e){

                    e.preventDefault();

                    data.formData = $("#form_news").serializeArray();
                    data.submit();


                });

            },
            done: function(e, data) {

                if(data){
                    window.location.reload();
                }

            },

            error: function(e, data){

                console.log(data);

            }

        });
```